# Why was InvocationTargetException designed to store its cause as target?

Tags: java, error-handling

I am wondering why `InvocationTargetException` was designed to store its cause as target, requiring everyone to unwrap it via `invocationTargetException.getTargetException()` instead of `invocationTargetException.getCause()`. This is one of the most occurring cases for bad error handling by logging incomplete/wrong stack traces. It seems like a bad design decision in the java language, or what is the purpose of this design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have a misconception that `getCause` doesn't return the same value as `getTargetException`, as it does return the same value. It is just that `getCause` didn't exist in earlier Java versions. `InvocationTargetException` has existed since Java 1.1, while general exception chaining was only introduced in Java 1.4.

To quote from [`InvocationTargetException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/InvocationTargetException.html) (emphasis mine):

> As of release 1.4, this exception has been retrofitted to conform to the general purpose exception-chaining mechanism. The "target exception" that is provided at construction time and accessed via the `getTargetException()` method is now known as the cause, and may be accessed via the `Throwable.getCause()` method, **as well as the aforementioned "legacy method."**

and the [`InvocationTargetException.getTargetException()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/InvocationTargetException.html#getTargetException--) documentation (emphasis mine):

> Get the thrown target exception.
>
> This method predates the general-purpose exception chaining facility. **The `Throwable.getCause()` method is now the preferred means of obtaining this information.**

If you look at the implementation of `getCause` and `getTargetException`, they have the same implementation:

> ```
> /**
>  * Get the thrown target exception.
>  *
>  * <p>This method predates the general-purpose exception chaining facility.
>  * The {@link Throwable#getCause()} method is now the preferred means of
>  * obtaining this information.
>  *
>  * @return the thrown target exception (cause of this exception).
>  */
> public Throwable getTargetException() {
>     return target;
> }
>
> /**
>  * Returns the cause of this exception (the thrown target exception,
>  * which may be {@code null}).
>  *
>  * @return  the cause of this exception.
>  * @since   1.4
>  */
> public Throwable getCause() {
>     return target;
> }
> ```

Comment: Since 1.1 actually, there was no reflection in 1.0.

Comment: @EJP thanks, edited it. As there was no `@since`, I assumed it was already there in Java 1.0

Comment: you are right, seems my memory was a bit flaky on this, I remember having to treat InvocationTargetException specially some time ago, but maybe I am just wrong. The only problem I see with InvocationTargetException now is that .initCause(cause) does not work properly on it, since it does not override the target exception.